# Ubuntu 16.04LTS starting with some error code

Tags: boot, 16.04, hard-drive

Recently I upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 LTS. System is starting every time with some code

```
**[[D^[[D^........**
**/dev/sda1: Clearing orphaned inode 17301798 (uid=0, gid=0, mode=0100644, size=29231097)**
.
.
.
```

Comment: It's nothing just Ubuntu doing some `in-house-cleaning` before a fresh `boot` :)

Comment: You can shut that down in the `/etc/default/grub` file if it irritates you .

Comment: @George i am new with Ubuntu, could u please give me some idea how to do dis.

Comment: Please run this from the terminal and post the result in your question: `cat /etc/default/grub`